# Radius of convergence and domain of convergence for $\sum^\infty_{n=1} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})2^nx^{2n}$

Tags: power-series

The original series is
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})2^nx^{2n}.$$
I used The absolute value of the ratio of the latter item to the former item to do this problem.
$2\left|\frac{(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1})y}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right|$
（$y=x^2$）I used it to replace $x^2$.

How can I continue to reduce the series to a formula with a constant and $|x^2|$ to get the radius of convergence?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Kenny Wong Thanks for your edition

Comment: @Dianqing No problem. However, we're waiting for your own edit - to provide context about your own thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test? If so, show us where you start having trouble.

Comment: @MasB I can't continue to reduce the equation when it comes to $\frac{(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})2x}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: It is not $2x$ but $x^2$  in your last comment. Use a binomial expansion and long division (or Taylor series). It is simple.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Could you show the detailed step for me i just can't find why $x^2$ is right.And the method you told is out of my learning range.Still thanks to u anyway.

Comment: Everybody here is ready to **help** you but no one will do your homework. Show some working, please.

Comment: Based on $\lim_{n\to +∞}\vert{\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}}=l\vert{x}$ I transformed  it to $\frac{(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})2^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})2^{n}x^{2n}}$. But I can only get $2x$ not the $x^{2}$

Comment: Are you online now?@ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: $x^{2n}$ becomes $x^{2(n+1)}=x^{2n+2}$ If you showed what you have done, we could have caught this error at the start of the conversation.

Comment: @MasB Thanks for your answer.But when i got $|\frac{(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})2x^{2}}{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}|$.I can't get a formula which is like to $l|x|$

Comment: Let $y=x^2$, Apply the tools you know to find the radius of convergence for the resultant series in $y$. Then figure out what that radius tells you about the radius of convergence in the original series in $x$.

Comment: @Dianqing Note that $$
\left| {2\frac{{\sqrt {n + 2}  + \sqrt {n + 1} }}{{\sqrt {n + 1}  + \sqrt n }}y} \right| \to 2|y| = 2|x|^2 
$$ as $n\to+\infty$. Now you want this to be less than $1$ to ensure convergence (via ratio test). What does that give you for $|x|$?

Comment: @Gary Because my textbook told me I have to get $l|x|$(l is a constant) and use the public formula $R=\frac{1}{l}$ to get the radius of convergence. So is that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ the radius,right?

Comment: @Dianqing Yes, it is.